# Is there an R function for converting a dataset into the appropriate format for a Latent Class Analysis?

Tags: r

I'm a beginner with LCA so I apologise if this is a basic question, I tried to google it but could not find an answer. I want to conduct a LCA on a dataset I have (in excel). Some of the variables are binary (female/male, literate/illiterate...) and some have multiple levels (married, single, widowed, divorced). I understand that for the binary variables I can convert them into 1s and 0s, however I don't know what to do about the ones with multiple levels. Is there an R function that will convert them to a format accepted by poLCA? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Dummy encoding in R is done implicitly, so you can just name columns of the table which aren't numbers:

```
library(poLCA)
data(election)
poLCA(cbind(AGE, PARTY, CARESB) ~ GENDER, data = election)
```